# Coin Tossing Expected Reward and Decision Rule

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value

Consider a scenario where you are given 10 coins with unknown biases. All we know is that the probability of heads for any coin follows $Beta(5,5)$.

Given $100$ tosses, and a reward of $+1$ for heads, and $+0$ for tails, what is the expected reward from playing this game optimally (i.e. optimal in the sense of maximizing overall reward over the tosses)? You can toss any coin at each step.

An intuitive approach would be to start by flipping a random coin, maintaining an estimate of the bias (all start off at $0.5$, update based on the number of heads tossed/total number of times the coin is tossed). At each step, pick the coin with the highest estimated bias (if multiple are the same, pick one that has been tossed less). However, it is not clear to me whether

1. this approach is optimal or
2. how to calculate the expected reward (i.e. how much to pay to play the game).

At the least, can someone provide an *estimate* as to what the expected reward would be under this/some optimal strategy -- it doesn't need to be closed form. Saw this as an interview question elsewhere and it has been bugging me all day!

Comment: Normal model isn't good because $p$ needs to be in $[0,1]$ why not beta distribution?

Comment: Yep, I agree. I saw the question on a different website, and a normal clearly doesn't make much sense. Let's go with a bell-shaped Beta (say $Beta(5,5)$) instead. Indeed, I am okay with any prior on the distribution of coin weights. I am just struggling with computing the expected value.

Comment: Why would you choose the coin whose bias you are **less sure** of, instead of the one where your evidence is better to favour the bias observed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here? I was just thinking that if multiple coins have the same ratio of heads/tails, then since we want to eventually toss the maximally biased coin most often, I'd think we want to incentivize exploring the less tossed coins where there is a bigger chance of the bias being higher than that indicated by evidence. It's basically a multi-armed bandit problem but I don't know how to get an expectation.